# Get OpenVPN clients names to resolve through dnsmasq

Tags: openvpn, dnsmasq

I have a PFSense box running as an OpenVPN server. There are several remote devices that connect through the VPN (as tap devices).

The VPN stuff is working, I can access the remote hardware by looking up the IP assigned to each device on the PFSense router.

What I'd like is to have it so I can resolve the remote hardware addresses via DNS while on the local network. Note that this is only local-network -> remote-device (they're backup boxes). I don't need to have the remote devices resolve using the local DNS forwarding agent.

I have the rest of the devices on the network that need to be accessible via DNS report their name during the DHCP process. However, the IP assignment for OpenVPN tap clients, while it *is* dynamic (which is why I need DNS), does not seem to use the local DHCP server.

How can I have my openvpn server add information for it's clients to the dnsmask resolver? Is this setup even reasonable (I'm not familiar with openVPN at all)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the routes from the server to the clients.

I have never used pfsense but on the openvpn client.

You'd do

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass dhcp"
```